# "ich sprecht [...]"; is this a typo?

Tags: conjugation, typo

In the notes of [nthuleen](https://www.nthuleen.com/101/hausaufgaben/ws03klassenzimmerantw.html), it is given that

> A: Sprechen Sie Englisch?
>
> B: Nein, ich sprecht kein Englisch (oder: Nein, ich spreche nicht Englisch).

However, in the answer, it conjugates the verb as "sprecht" with *ich*. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Olafant what if it wasn't? then would it be a viable question? If so, I couldn't have known that until I had asked and gotten an answer!

Comment: For future reference, it's better to keep the title and the question in the same language. The custom here is to answer the question in the same language in which it was asked, and if you use both languages then it's hard to tell how the question should be answered.

Comment: @RDBury got it. thanks for the remark

Comment: @Our: please use the same question for the title and the body of a question. You wrote the title in German but the body in English. This makes it hard to decide in which language comments and answers shall be given. Since all comments here are in English, I translated the title and answered in English.

Comment: @Olafant: Being about a typo is not a reason to close a question. This is not Stack Overflow (where there are good reasons for closing typo-based questions). If the question otherwise fulfils our quality requirements, I see no problem if it is about a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form *sprecht* of the verb *sprechen* is:

- 2. Person Plural Imperativ Präsens Aktiv

  > Na los, **sprecht** endlich miteinander!
- 2. Person Plural Indikativ Präsens Aktiv

  > Warum **sprecht** ihr nicht miteinander?

The form *sprecht* can not be used for 1. person singular. So, I can clearly say: The sentence from the question is wrong because the required form is:

- 1. Person Singular Indikativ Präsens Aktiv

  > Nein, ich **spreche** kein Englisch.

But it's hard to say if this error was a typo or not. An error is a typo when you wanted to press a certain key (here: e) but by accident caught another key (here: t). Maybe the author thought *sprecht* was correct and typed in on purpose. In this case it was no typo.